# Connection timeout when calling the send api using EmailJS

Tags: reactjs, api, email

```
 send(
   'service_id',
   'template_id',
   toSend,
   'user_id',
 )
   .then((response) => {
     console.log('SUCCESS!', response.status, response.text);
     alert('Sent!');
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     console.log('FAILED...', err);
   });
```

Here is my code. I don't know what's happening but even if I test the sample template from their site my emails can't push through. Btw, I'm using Gmail as my registered mailing service.

Comment: https://www.emailjs.com/

Comment: Have you tried the function `sendForm`, from the react example?